# Terminal Services Session Broker: can I set it up with just one Terminal Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

I have two Terminal Servers: one is 2008 R2, the other one (that's currently in production) is 2003 Standard, which is not supported by the 2008 Session Broker/Load Balancing service.

What I'd like to do is setup the 2008 Session Broker service (with Network Load Balancer, not Round Robin DNS) with just the one new 2008 R2 Terminal Server for now.  This way, I can take down the 2003 Server and rebuild it, while all sessions are brokered to the new box, and when it's finished, add it to the farm.

Question #1: Is this doable?

All the remote sites connect to the existing Terminal Server through a static private network address over an IPSec tunnel.  In order to not have to change the RDP shortcut at a bunch of city-wide locations, I'd like to (after-hours) set the machine that'll be running the Network Load Balancing service to that IP, so that the next day, the remote sites will be connecting to the Load Balancer box, not a direct Terminal Server.

Question #2: Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1: Yes.

## 2: Yes.